# rm + how to remove file with special Characters

Tags: linux, ksh, rm

I have this file in my linux machine:

```
 ----------9976723563nneh4_-----192.9.200.4
```

I try to delete this file but I cant as all see here:

what need to add to rm in order to remove this file ?

```
rm "----------9976723563nneh4_-----192.9.200.4"
rm: illegal option -- --------9976723563nneh4_-----192.9.200.4
usage: rm [-fiRr] file ...
```

.

```
rm '----------9976723563nneh4_-----192.9.200.4'
rm: illegal option -- --------9976723563nneh4_-----192.9.200.4
usage: rm [-fiRr] file ...
```

Comment: From my point it will better to show this question , because rm is different from cd and

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rm -- ----------9976723563nneh4_-----192.9.200.4
```

You need `--` in order to tell `rm` (and more or less all other GNU software) that all following parameters are file names even when beginning with "-". Otherwise (and in your case) the file name is confused with options. Another possibility is

```
rm ./----------9976723563nneh4_-----192.9.200.4
```

**Edit 1**

Calling this trivial answer a "great solution" makes me feel obliged to take it to a higher level. The basic problem cannot be solved "better" but you can try to get used to always making `--` an argument. And some shell code (replacing rm by a shell function) can help you with this:

```
rm () {
  local args sep_found=no
  args=("$@")
  while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    if [ "--" = "$1" ]; then
      sep_found=yes
      break
    fi
    shift
  done
  if [ "yes" = "$sep_found" ]; then
    command rm "${args[@]}"
  else
    echo "WARNING: rm called without '--' seperator."
    echo "Please correct the command; aborting."
  fi
}
```

You would put this in e.g. `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: GREAT SOLUTION _ WOW _ -:)

Comment: @yael See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual page for `rm`:

> To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo', use one of these commands:
>
> rm -- -foo
>
> rm ./-foo

so to remove your file, try `rm -- ----------9976723563nneh4_-----192.9.200.4`.